# Link events for all <a> on Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Do you know how i can create 'click' events for all link (all template) in my Meteor App ?

I've try .on('click'), but i've no result.

My code on my Template.layout.rendered function :

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

let url = $(this).attr('href');

$('#js-container').addClass('is-animate');

setTimeout(function () {

    Router.go(url);

    $('#js-container').removeClass('is-animate').addClass('test');

}, 600);
})
```

This code work, but only for link in my layout template.

Thank you !

Comment: Could you please give us some code ? Do you use jQuery ?

Comment: Hi, i've edit my first post and add my code :) Yep, i use jquery

Comment: Are all of the anchor tags there on page load, or are they rendered dynamically?

Comment: Some link are add with other template, so dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. Hope this helps.

```
  function callback(e) {
    var e = window.e || e;

    if (e.target.tagName !== 'A')
        return;

    // Do something
}

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
else
    document.attachEvent('onclick', callback);
```

Comment: My code work, but not for all template meteor. Only for layout

Comment: I've updated the code. It uses event bubbling, so it will handle all the anchor tags even if they are added dynamically.